# How does the hour calculation work for the bounty grace period notice?

Tags: discussion, bounties, expired-bounty

When a question with the bounty in a grace period, it is displaying the notice like the one below:

But the summation of the **hours before bounty ended** + **Grace period ends** is always **23**. I would expect it to be 24, as in a whole day.

Is it a miscalculation?

How the hour calculation is works for the bounty grace period notice?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: They round hours.

Comment: If a single second is passed after a hour, it will be treated as anothet hour. Since you are from India, I can give you an example. Before arrival of DOCOMO, if you talk for 1 minute 1 second, it will be billed as 2 minutes. Like the same happens here